# Term for: "ease of use of finding the page I needed to" (like discoverability)

Tags: terminology, discoverability

What are all the correct UX terms for this situation:

1. A user needs to use your site to do something (like ask a question)
2. They load your webpage, follow links, and either
3. find the information they need or the "contact us" form

Ideally, each step of this process should be very smooth, and it should be obvious to the user at each step how they can further approach their goal.

What are the names of each step?

> The user has a _____ in mind (goal? use case?)

> The ______ was _____ (The target was discoverable? discoverability was great? something else?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two similar but different concepts here to consider when it comes to creating or structuring content for user consumption. According to the NNg website:

> **Findability**: Users can easily find content or functionality that they assume is present in a website.
>
> **Discoverability**: Users encounter new content or functionality that they were not aware of previously.

Based on your description, the term that is more applicable would be findability rather than discoverability.

Comment: Yes, certainly sounds like "findability" is exactly the word I needed.